# Maximum number of vpc per aws region across user accounts

Tags: amazon-vpc

How aws is able to manage so many vpcs with in a specific aws region considering that there are more vpcs per region than the private IPv4 address ranges can afford?.

Comment: Magic. Also not every box gets a public IP. But this question is too generic for this site. How does the answer affect your code?

Comment: i am new to aws and trying to get a thorough understanding of its architecture, especially the VPC and how it works behind the scenes.